# Password Change PHP

Tags: php, passwords

I am working on a simple script that allows users to create an account. There is nothing special about it, at it asks for is a username, and password. The only problem I'm having is creating a script that allows the user to change their password. Here is my progress.

Its saying "Your current password is not right!", even though the password is fine. I already have it to connect to the database with another code on the same page.

```
<?php
    $CurrentPassword  = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['CurrentPassword'])));
    $NewPassword    = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['NewPassword'])));
    $ConfirmNewPassword = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['ConfirmNewPassword'])));
    $Submit2      =    mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['Submit2'])));
?>
<?php
    if ($Submit2) {
       $_OLDHASH = hash('sha512',''.$CurrentPassword.'');
       $_NEWHASH = hash('sha512',''.$NewPassword.'');
       $_CONFIRMNEWHASH = hash('sha512',''.$ConfirmNewPassword.'');

       if ($myU->Password == $_OLDHASH) {
           if ($_NEWHASH == $_CONFIRMNEWHASH) {
               mysql_query("UPDATE Password='".$_NEWHASH."' WHERE Username='".$User."'");
               session_destroy();
               header("Location: index.php");
           }
           else {
               echo "Your new password and new confirm password does not match!";
           }
       }
       else {
           echo "Your current password is not right!";
       }
    }
?>


<form action='' method='POST'>
<br />
Update Password
<br />
<input placeholder='Current Password' type='password' name='CurrentPassword'>
<br />
<input placeholder='New Password' type='password' name='NewPassword'>
<br />
<input placeholder='Confirm New Password' type='password' name='ConfirmNewPassword'>
<br />
<input type='submit' value='Change' name='Submit2'><br />
</form>
```

Comment: So what's your actual question? What isn't working?

Comment: Well, its just saying invalid password, even though its a valid password. My guess is it an error with connecting to the database, but I'm not very good with database configuration.

Comment: None of the code here prints out 'invalid password', so you'll want to find that, for starters.

Comment: don't 'guess', debug.

Comment: Your current password is not right!, my mistake.

Comment: I have debugged. Is two weeks long enough or should I wait a few more years until asking for help without people hating?

Comment: You should `var_dump` the values of `$myU->Password` and `$_NEWHASH` and check that same value in your database. That should give you an indication of where the problem is.

Comment: then you know if your connection to the db is the issue or not ? If you don't like the free help, go pay for some.

Comment: Thankfully there is help now. But you need to do some research on the word help, as its definition does not include people such as you saying to do it yourself. If that is what you believe in, I do not think this website is suited for you.

Comment: you joined today, i joined 2 years ago, i think i know a little more about how S.O works than you

Comment: Just because someone joined today doesn't mean they have used the site for one day. In fact I joined this site in 2009, I simply do not remember my username and/or password. Also, age has nothing to do with wisdom. It can help, but not in all cases. At least I can use semi-proper grammar.

Comment: here is some help: http://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

Comment: Some people just don't understand... Its sad. :(

Comment: i couldn't agree more :-)

Comment: I agree with @Dagon. Debug. Try `var_dump($myU->Password)`. If it produces a hash, it's not a problem with your database. Maybe you really *ARE* entering the wrong password. You did forget your SO password, right? Try manually resetting the password hash and checking again. I don't know how you could take 2 weeks to debug 20 or so lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

When you check the password on login are you also doing all of this extraneous crap to it?

```
mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes()))
```

Because I can see that causing issues with a password containing special characters, aka: a strong password. My advice is to not do that at all, you're hashing the input before including it in the query, so there's no chance of SQL injection with this particular field.

Other things wrong:

1. `''.$NewPassword.''` is equivalent to simply `$NewPassword`
2. Why?

   ```
   ?>
   <?php
   ```

   This will output a raw line break which is going to break your `header()` call.

Answer (score 2):

try to make two files:

changePass.html :

```
<form action='changePass.php' method='POST'>
<br />
Update Password
<br />
<input placeholder='Current Password' type='password' name='CurrentPassword'>
<br />
<input placeholder='New Password' type='password' name='NewPassword'>
<br />
<input placeholder='Confirm New Password' type='password' name='ConfirmNewPassword'>
<br />
<input type='submit' value='Change' name='Submit2'><br />
</form>
```

and second copyPass.php:

```
<?php
//    Copy your php code here
?>
```

So, when user wants to change pass, point him to changePass.html, and when he enters the form, data will be transmited and processed to changePass.php. Please notice that in form tag / action parameter is added changePass.php as webpage which will process data.

Now I also noticed wrong syntax in your SQL query, you should write something like:

mysql_query("UPDATE `passwordTable`  `SET` Password='".$_NEWHASH."' WHERE Username='".$User."'");